# What would happen if I changed the NS records in DNS Zone files to another NS server and Kept by the registrar at the TLD DNS servers the same>

Tags: dns, domain-name

Thank you for your help in advance,

I have been reading on the internet for almost 2 days and I could not find any decisive answer to it.

**The Senario**

I have a domain I would like to change the currently NS records to a new NS servers in the Zone files, but at the same time I would like to keep the  registrar DNS servers values as it is.

**The Question**

What would happen in this case exactly, and which servers would be answering the DNS query once the change in the NS records has been propagated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would not be a best practice.

If you modify the zone in the current provider to point to a different DNS servers this should in theory mostly work, but it is inefficient and cant be guaranteed(its sometimes done while migrating a zione as a short term measure)

There is, if-course no technical reasin you cant delegate the subdomains to other nameservers using NS records , although there is a slight performance penalty.

I do note that most registrars (im not aware if any that dont) will allow you to specify nameservers other then theirs - this us the approriate way of doing things (but if I understand your post correctly you are saying this is not an ootion for you)

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
Basically, This started out during  DNS Migration project, but it ended up to be a theoretical question to verify my understanding.
So what would be the possible reasons that this method would not work?

Comment: Not sure. Resolver implementation maybe? Wildly speculating with no evidence you may not want this behavioyr as it could indicate a DNS compromise. I also postulate it could break DNSSEC if implemented.